# How can I hide the file name when install a program?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

I am using InstallShield 2010 to build the installer of my project and I would like to hide the name of files showed while  they are transferred to HD:

[image]

Can I hide the file name and keep the progress bar? Or even to suppress the window and replace it by another?

Anyone have any idea about how can I do this?

Comment: can you compile your installshield project into an MSI as opposed to a InstallShield EXE? You can always do a msiexec /i name.msi /qb

Comment: Stackoverflow allows you to upload images and display them in your question. It makes things simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SetStatusWindow" function in installscript to overcome this. An example is in InstallShield site itself: [SetStatusWindow Example](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15langref/LangrefSetStatusWindow_example.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To enable the display of the name and path of the file being installed on the second line of the status bar, call Enable with the `INDVFILESTATUS` parameter before calling `FeatureMoveData`.

```
Enable(STATUSEX);
Disable(INDVFILESTATUS);
...
SetStatusWindow(100, "Setup is complete.");
Disable(STATUSEX);
```